# Angular: change style depending on *ngIf condition

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-ng-if

I'm aware that I can do something like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="user.age<18;else over">
  <div class="some-section" style="background-color: red;">
    [...]
  </div>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #over>
  <div class="some-section" style="background-color: blue;">
    [...]
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

Although this works, it is duplicate code. Is there a way to change only the style so that there's no duplicates (scss, other angular tools, ...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question title mentions style we'll only apply styles using `[ngStyle]`

To only change style, you can use the `[ngStyle]` instead of `[ngClass]` which adds a class instead of styles. Using your code as an example it should look like this:

```html
<div class="some-section" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': (user.age < 18) ? 'red' : ((user.age >= 18) ? 'blue' : null) }">
  [...]
</div>
```

Also using `[ngStyle]` and `[ngClass]` for adding styles and classes will help you bind a string of classes, an array of strings, or an object. For more complex scenarios.

Comment: Is it possible to change two instances in one [ngStyle]?

Comment: By 2 instances you mean adding 2 different styles for a single div?

Answer (score 2):

Too **change a style depending on a condition**, you only have to use this:

```
[style.xxx]="expression"
```

Example:

```
<div class="some-section" [style.backgroundColor]="age < 18 ? 'red' : 'blue'">
```

Or via *function*, for more "complex" calculations without messing up HTML

```
<div class="some-section" [ngStyle]="calculateStyles()">

calculateStyles() {
   if (user.age<18) { 
      return "background-color: red";
   } else {
      return "background-color: blue";
   }
}
```

And then, **the "better" way to manage your styles depending on conditions, using a class instead of just just "styles"**:

```
[ngClass]="expression"
```

Example:

```
<div class="some-section" [ngClass]="{'classACSS': user.age<18, 'classBCSS': user.age>=18}"

.classACSS {
background-color: red;
}

.classBCSS {
background-color: blue;
}
```

I leave you [HERE](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ngclass-ngstyle/) the doc with a more detailed explanation of all of this.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do that:

```
  <div class="some-section"
       [style.backgroundColor]="age > 18 ? 'red' : 'blue'">
    [...]
  </div>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w6l8pg)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it check out this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```html
<div class="some-section" style="background-color: {{age < 18 ? 'red' : 'blue'}}">
  Test
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="some-section" [style.backgroundColor]="age < 18 ? 'red' : 'blue'">
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<div class="some-section" *ngIf="user.age<18" style="background-color:red;">
  [...]
</div>
<div class="some-section" *ngIf="user.age>18" style="backdrop-color:blue">
  [...]
</div>
```